# What is the difference between a , &a and *a?

Tags: c, pointers, pointer-to-pointer

I am trying to understand the difference between `a` and `&a` when a is a pointer.

in the following example code :

```
int main()
{
    int b = 100;
    int *a;
    a = &b;
    printf("%d %d %d", a , &a , *a);
    return 0;
}
```

According to my understanding, a is a **name** given to the address of a. That is :

[image]

Therefore I am expecting `a` and `&a` to be same when `a` is a pointer. But in the output, I am getting the first two values ( `a` and `&a` ) as different.

Where am I going wrong ?

Comment: *According to my understanding, `a` a name given to the address of `a`.* This is a misunderstanding. `a` is a name that represents a value that is at a specific address. So using `a` you access the value. Using `&a` you access the address of the value represented by `a`. And then `*a` assumes the value represented by `a` is itself an address, and `*a` refers to the value at that address.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, use `%p` and cast the argument to `void *` for printing a pointer. Passing an incompatible (mismatched) type of argument for any conversion specification is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

That said, even a pointer variable, is a variable, and has to be "stored" in an address. So, it's the address of a pointer type variable.

In other words,

- `b` is a variable (of type `int`) and it has an address.
- `a` is a variable (of type `int *`) and it *also* has an address.

---

To add some reference, quoting `C11`, chapter §6.5.3.2,

> The operand of the unary `&` operator shall be either a function designator, the result of a
>   `[]` or unary `*` operator, or **an lvalue that designates an object that is not a bit-field and is
>   not declared with the `register` storage-class specifier.**

and, from §6.3.2.1,

> An lvalue is an expression (with an object type other than `void`) that potentially
>   designates an object. [...]

Comment: So, in the above diagram, *a = 100, &a = 0x77e4 and a = 0x867f . Is that correct ?

Comment: @SeverusTux precisely, yes.

Answer (score 1):

Its probably more easily explained by the following simple code example:

> printf("%d %d %d %d %d", &a , a , *a, &b, b);

which returns for example:

```
290289632 290289644 100 290289644 100
```

- The address of a: &a is something allocated at start up (output item
  1).
- a points to the address of b hence output item 2 and 4 are the
  same.
- The value at the address *a = b: hence output item 3 and 5 are
  the same.

Comment: Remember that all variable created in a programmes startup phase must have different address spaces allocated to them. Therefore the address of a and b must be different.

Answer (score 0):

Here basically *a stores the value of b which is 100,&a is the address of the pointer a itself since it is also a variable and thus must have an address, and a refers to the address of the variable is pointing to(b's address in this case)